# How to sort an Excel column using the following characters

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have a column with letters `W` and `E` following numbers, i.e.

```
4e
5w
6w
7e
7e
```

, and I want to sort the column into `e` and `w`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Select your Range and go to **Data>Text in Rows**.

Follow the dialogue by selecting Fixed width and setting a dividing line between 4 and e - continue.

Your original column is now split into 2 columns like so:

```
      A     B
---------------
1 |   4     e
2 |   5     w
3 |   6     w
4 |   7     e
5 |   7     e
```

Then you select the B column and do a Sort A - Z on it - excel will ask if you want to extend your selection to column A - finish by accepting. Done